# How do we perform hyperparameter tuning on parameter of data augmentation?

Tags: neural-networks, hyperparameter, data-augmentation, tuning

I was wondering how do we perform hyperparameter tuning on parameters of data augmentation. Suppose I have to select the best pair of (alpha, alpha) values of beta distribution that works best on data augmentation and produce the highest accuracy on my model. my question is how do we do it? can I somehow use Keras tuner for that? if you know any link to something similar I will really appreciate it if you guide me there?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ablation study by training the same model and hyperparameter tuning, but varying the magnitude of augmentation and observe the results. The authors of [Albumentation library](https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations) used this approach, documented at the end of [their paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2078-2489/11/2/125/htm)